# Questions with the same title

Tags: discussion, feature-request, title-wording

I asked [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5105/1651) using the title "What show is this?"  Being familiar with SE sites, I realized that the title I used is no longer available for future questions.

Given that this community accepts these kinds of questions I can imagine this title being used again.  Perhaps it is a case where titles should be updated to be more specific, but I'm nor sure.  Is there a way that we can bypass the "A question with this title already exists"?

Comment: Perhaps try using more descriptive titles in the future? I.e., What show is this that involves (brief description of the characters depicted).

Comment: @Krazer Kinda what I figured, but for the sake of new users with similar questions I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is a more descriptive title.

Think about it this way, if you were looking the show on Google, what would you expect to look for?

For your case, I'd probably do something like:

> From which anime are the characters in this screenshot from?

Or something similar. You can even go as far as describe the characters to some extent (Blue hair, glasses, white and blue cat on the shoulder and a blonde, short girl with a pink cat on her shoulder).

Be specific.

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer. My suggestion for the title was "What anime is this comparison of releases from?", but anything descriptive enough that it will be easy to find in the future for us and others searching for it is fine.